# QGIS - Problem with Print Layout - blacked out sections on map (QQIS 3.2.1-Bonn)

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I am experiencing a problem with  Print Layout. When importing my map, random blacked out sections are appearing.

[image]

Comment: *Explict Content*?

Comment: Did you have symbol at those location ? In the past I had  issue with symbol in map unit that displayed at a wrong size in composer at certain scale....

Comment: No, i don't have symbols at those locations. when changing the scale/zoom they move around.